# Put, patch and delete don't return errors

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, api, mongoose

I'm currently developing a REST API with JS, but I have the following problem:
The code works but if I try to delete,put or patch a entry which does not exist, it does not return the error but it prints the success message. Why is that? The get route works perfectly.

```
app.route("/verbrauch/:parameterVariable")

    .get((req, res) => {
        Verbrauch.findOne({
            bezeichnung: req.params.parameterVariable
        }, (err, gefundeneEintraege) => {
            if (gefundeneEintraege) {
                res.send(gefundeneEintraege);
            } else {
                res.send("Success");
            }
        });
    })


    .put((req, res) => {
        Verbrauch.update({
                bezeichnung: req.params.parameterVariable
            }, {
                bezeichnung: req.body.bezeichnung,
                stueckzahl: req.body.stueckzahl,
                monat: req.body.monat,
                jahr: req.body.jahr,
            }, {
                overwrite: true
            },
            err => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("Success");
                } else {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        );
    })


    .patch((req, res) => {
        Verbrauch.update({
                bezeichnung: req.params.parameterVariable
            }, {
                $set: req.body
            },
            err => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("Success")
                } else {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        );
    })

    .delete((req, res) => {
        Verbrauch.deleteOne({
                bezeichnung: req.params.parameterVariable
            },
            err => {
                if (!err) {
                    res.send("Success");
                } else {
                    res.send(err);
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Update method will be with callback function with 2 parameters(error, writeOpResult). Try with below solution

```
app.put((req, res) => {
    Verbrauch.update({
            bezeichnung: req.params.parameterVariable
        }, {
            bezeichnung: req.body.bezeichnung,
            stueckzahl: req.body.stueckzahl,
            monat: req.body.monat,
            jahr: req.body.jahr,
        }, {
            overwrite: true
        },
        (err,res) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.send("Success");
            } else {
                res.status(404).send(err);
            }
        }
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons for this.

Firstly, If you try to update something which does not exist in the database. It will not return err and it will return ***null*** in the result.

Secondly, You should not write res.send(err). Because, if you just write res.send then ExpressJs will add default status code as 200 which is an indication for success. 
 You can give

> res.status(400).send(err)

or

> res.status(500).send(err)